# Heroku NODE_ENV is set for me as development instead off production

Tags: node.js, heroku, environment-variables, production, nodeenv

Hi from everywhere I have read about the Heroku environment variable NODE_ENV is that they set it as production for everyone but for me some odd reason it is set for me as development. How can I change it back to production?

I have even tried to force it to be production by going to settings then Reveal config vars and manually putting in NODE_ENV production. but as I tested it out with winston logger I get back that NODE_ENV is development. This is very strange.

Why is it like this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try install cross-env and add `cross-env NODE_ENV=*MODE*` to you'r npm start script in `package.json`, like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production nest start"
},
```

Comment: Nope that doesn't help as my Heroku log is still showing as development
```2021-10-07 23:29:07 [32minfo[39m: What value is NODE_ENV
2021-10-07 23:29:07 [32minfo[39m: development
2021-10-07 23:29:07 [32minfo[39m: What value is NODE_ENV```

Logger using winston